# How to exclude linebreak-only textnodes from text() XPath query?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I want to query all textnodes from my DOM. However, I don't want to have these "markup-linebreaks", where there is a linebreak between HTML tags.

So I'm trying to translate all whitespaces according [to here](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200107/post61340.html) and check if there're chars left:

```
/html/body//text()[not(translate(., '&#20;&#x9;&#xA;&#xD;', '') = '')]
```

This doesn't work, since it doesn't seams to be possible to check agains empty strings (which kind of makes sense, since it's not a text node then).

*Any other approach to filter this nodes?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/html/body//text()[normalize-space()]
```

This selects all text-node descendants of `/html/body` each of which has a non-empty string value after normalization.

**The above expression uses the standard XPath function [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)** which takes a string (or the string-value of the context-node, if specified with no argument) and returns another one in which all leading and trailing whitespace characters are deleted and any intermediate group of adjacent whitespace characters has been replaced by a single space.

Comment: @AronWoost: This is pure XPath 1.0 (click on the link to verify :) ) and works with any XPath 1.0 engine -- so it must work with the current browsers.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that link. Thanks for the solution! Pretty simple solution considering I spend 2h to find something on the interweb... :)