# XPath expression to get the values of child attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to get the value of child attributes from a sample XML file:

```
<book id="123">
<title>Game of Thrones</title>
<season>5</season>
</book>
```

My XPath expression is `/book`, but with this I am able to get only the value of `id`.

If my XML is like this:

```
<book> 
   <id>123</id>
   <title>Game of Thrones</title>
   <season>5</season>
</book>
```

...and if I give the expression as `/book`, I am not getting any values.

Expected result:

```
123
Game of Thrones
5
```

Comment: thanks andy, Since am new to this i didnt frame my question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Given Xml like this

```
<books>
  <book>
    <id>123</id>
    <title>Game of Thrones</title>
    <season>5</season>
  </book>
  <book>
    <id>124</id>
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <season>5</season>
  </book>
</books>
```

This Xpath will retrieve elements of given id

> /books/book[id=124]

Comment: nope.. it doesnt work. And i dont need one particular value. if i have multiple book details i need to get all the child values. So that i can update accordingly in a table

Answer (score 0):

If your XML document indeed looks like

```
<book> 
   <id>123</id>
   <title>Game of Thrones</title>
   <season>5</season>
</book>
```

and you indeed would like to result to be

```
123
Game of Thrones
5
```

Then, you are looking for the *text nodes* present in the input document. An XPath expression that selects all text nodes in a document is

```
//text()
```

This will also select text nodes that only contain whitespace, so the result might look like (individuall results separated by `-------`):

```
-----------------------
123
-----------------------
-----------------------
Game of Thrones
-----------------------
-----------------------
5
-----------------------
```

As you can see, there are whitespace-only lines in the result, but the exact behaviour depends on your XPath engine and how you display the results.

---

If linebreak-only lines should be excluded, use a predicate:

```
//text()[normalize-space()]
```

This technique is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8520899/1987598). Basically, the predicate returns True if there is text content left after normalizing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

For the xml specified as second example in your question you can get all children elements values using this XPath expression:

```
/book[id=123]/child::*/text()
```

Actually, `/book[id=123]`selects `<book>` element having id = 123, `child::*` gets its children, and `text()` gets text from children.

Comment: It is not necessary to use `child::`, because `child::` is the default axis step anyway. Simply use `.../*/...`.